# Как получить ответ от Google Maps API на русском?

Tags: php, google-maps-api, google-maps

юзаю Google Maps Geocoding API, если делать get запрос, то локации приходят транслитом на латинеце.

```
$request_params = array('latlng' => $item->end_location->lat . ',' .$item->end_location->lng);
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
$res = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'.$get_params));
```

Если же посылать запрос прям через браузер

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=55.6858518,52.4851357
```

то всё нормально и приходит ответ локаций на русском

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было мне подробнее читать документацию.. Добавляем в параметры

```
'language'=>'ru'
```

И наблюдаем ответ на предпочитаемом языке